# Why does my vCard display as *.vcf file on iOS?

Tags: ios, twilio, vcf-vcard, mms, imessage

I want to send [vCards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) (a.k.a. contact cards) to my customers as MMS.

Sometimes that message displays nicely in iOS iMessages: Contact name and icon with name initials.
[How I want the vCard to display on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2q2m.jpg)

However, more often it displays badly: Generic icon and `File Name.vcf`. [How the vCard actually displays on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMQU.jpg)

I am concerned that this uncommon file extension will look suspicious to users and they will not save the contact card in their phones thinking it may be malware. I have researched and tested but I can not figure out why it doesn't always display the nice way.

Details about my setup:

- Usually the vCard will be sent to customers:

  - from a Twilio number they do not have saved in their phone
  - but they have called before (they find the number online)
  - and they have received another text message from that number about an hour earlier.
- I use [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging)'s HTTP API to programatically send an MMS where the attached media is the VCF file.
- I control the server that serves the vCards. It follows [The Twilio tutorial for vCards](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/send-vcard-twilio-sms):

  - The *.vcf file is version 2.1.
  - Http `Content-Disposition` header is `inline; filename="Shop Name.vcf"`
  - Http `Content-Type` header is `text/vcard`.
  - Http `Cache-Control` header is `no-cache`.
- The vCard is well formatted and displays well on Android.

I have tried:

- removing the `.vcf` extension from the `Content-Disposition` header `filename`
- Using `text/x-vcard` as the `Content-Type` header.
- Sending vCards manually between two phones. At first they appear as `.vcf` file but after some interaction they start being displayed the nice way. However I can not pinpoint or find any docs on what conditions need to be met.